# I'm unable to alter the Oracle parameter 'estimate_percent' from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

```
using (var command = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
{
       command.CommandText = "DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS";
       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ownname", schemaname));                        
       command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tabname", tablename));
       //command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("estimate_percent", 10));
       //command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("estimate_percent", Decimal.Parse("10")));
       //command.Parameters.Add("estimate_percent", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 10;                            
       int ret = command.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
 }
```

All commented out methods result in error - ORA-20001: 10 is an invalid identifier. The Oracle datatype for estimate_percent is number.

Answer (score 0):

Try using explicit OracleDb Types in your parameter declarations:

```
using (var command = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ownname", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tabname", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("estimate_percent", OracleDbType.Decimal));

    command.Parameters[0].Value = schemaname;
    command.Parameters[1].Value = tablename;
    command.Parameters[2].Value = 10M;

    int ret = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same "ORA-20001: 10 is an invalid identifier" error with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Accidently stumbled across the solution. Oracle was referencing the parameters in sequential order, not by name. 'estimate_percent' is the 4th parameter, so I simply added the 3rd parameter 'partname' and it worked.